# SparseGPT code reproduction

Tags: natural-language-processing, large-language-models

SparseGPT: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.00774.pdf

Pruning on the super large language model based on the Transformers structure has achieved a high compression rate with a small loss of accuracy. Is there any related code reproduction or research?

Someone mentioned on https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT, but no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorities released their code:
https://github.com/IST-DASLab/sparsegpt